# group by in sql value with json format in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data like below in my table

```
key         value
department  maths
department  science
class       one
class       two
book        science
book        maths
department  Tamil
book        SS
class       ten
```

in this table i want to get like below

```
"department":{
department : maths,
department :scicence
},
"class":{
 class : one,
class :two
}
```

in sql it self

Comment: If this is for "postgressql", why are you tagging SQL Server and MySQL...?

Comment: That sentence makes no sense I'm afraid. Postgresql, MySQL and SQL Server are all completely different RDBMS owned by completely different companies.

Comment: As an aside, duplicate key names in the same object in your JSON are likely going to make life hard for you, at least from a development aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange but posible.

Warning the output is a strange pseudo JSON because it has repeated keys:

This does what you want:

```
create table data1 (
  key text,
  value text
);

insert into data1(key,value) values 
('department','maths'),
('department','science'),
('class','one'),
('class','two'),
('book','science'),
('book','maths'),
('department','Tamil'),
('book','SS'),
('class','ten');

select json_object_agg(key, joined_values)::text
  from (
    select key, json_object_agg(key, value) joined_values
      from data1
      group by key
  ) data_joined;
```

If you do not want repeated keys in the object you can use an array inside

```
select json_object_agg(key, joined_values) 
  from (
    select key, json_agg(value) joined_values
      from data1
      group by key
  ) data_joined;
```